# How can I get the page title of every product in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I made a new Controller and inside there a new action. Inside there I want to be able to get the page title and the H1 of every product page. Is this possible?  Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Same as your other question ... just replace "meta_description" with "name"?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

`$productName = $_product->getName();`

**For the h1:**

```
<?php if($productName): ?>
    <h1><?php echo $productName; ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**For the page title :**

```
<?php $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($productName); ?>
```

Clear your cache !

Comment: This is not working at all...   :-(

Comment: It should work, you're talking about product page `view.phtml` ? don't forget to clear your cache

Comment: You are right. I had to clear the cache.   I still can't see the title though

Comment: look my update please

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in our controller action,

```
$this->loadLayout();  
$productId = '4'; // Get product ID dynamically
$productName = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getName();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($productName);
$this->renderLayout();
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: $this->loadLayout() makes it load forever. If I comment it out I get the following error:    Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() on boolean  EDIT:  It takes forever because there a looot of products. So I put a counter for 10 products so it can debug. But I don't anything printed...

Comment: The product page will have only one product, then why you put a count 10?

Comment: Because I want to load all the products of every page, so I'm only putting 10 for debugging. So  I am loading the productId I call the Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(*)  and then in a foreach($prodctId as $id) {$prodId = $id->getId();}   But your snippet only throws this error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() on boolean"

Comment: Can you please explain your functionality? Usually we are not all the products name as a page title. The $this->loadLayout(); should be called before set the page title.